# Storing summernote images in a database

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, summernote

I've done so far the following:

Ajax request:

```
        $('#description').summernote({
            callbacks: {
                onImageUpload: function(files) {
                    for(var i=0; i < files.length; i++) {
                        $.upload('image', files[i]);
                    } 
                }
            }
        });

        $.upload = function (file) {
            let out = new FormData();
            out.append('file', file, file.name);

            $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/summer-uploads',
                //check laravel document: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token
                headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data: out,
                success: function (r) {
                    $('#description').summernote('insertImage', r.url);
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.error(textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
                }
            });
        };
```

Controller:

```
public function summerUploads(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        $file = $request->input('image');

        $store = $file->store('summer-uploads');

        return url() . '/summer-uploads/' . $store;
    }

    return App::abort(404);
}
```

Routes:

```
Route::any('summer-uploads', 'AdminController@summerUploads');
```

If i try to upload an image, i'm getting the error: 500 (Internal Server Error) in console. If i try to in POSTMAN, i do get "The page has expired due to inactivity. " My CSRF token in meta is present, what could be an issue?

**UPDATE 1.**

I've spotted the error in chrome devtools:

```
{message: "Call to a member function store() on null",…}
exception
:
"Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError"
file
:
"/Users/username/Sites/PROJECTNAME/app/Http/Controllers/AdminController.php"
line
:
174
message
:
"Call to a member function store() on null"
```

Comment: Did you check the server log for the error?

Comment: yes, nothing regards my error

Comment: When I mean server log I mean the web server log. not laravel log.

Comment: Yes, i mean nginx error log. Is there a way to get more detailed error, not just 500?